# Move point to beginning of file name in WDired

Tags: dired

Example:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bs bs 20598 Jul 28 14:55 I-am-a-file.txt
                                              ^(cursor here)
```

A magic shortcut key is pressed, then:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bs bs 20598 Jul 28 14:55 I-am-a-file.txt
                                      ^(cursor here)
```

Does this magic shortcut key exist?

Reference:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Wdired.html

Answer (score 2):

> Does the magic shortcut key exist?

The closest you can get without writing your own command is by setting the user option `wdired-use-dired-vertical-movement` to a non-`nil` value:

```
wdired-use-dired-vertical-movement is a variable defined in ‘wdired.el’.
Its value is nil

Documentation:
If t, the "up" and "down" movement works as in Dired mode.
That is, always move the point to the beginning of the filename at line.

If ‘sometimes’, only move to the beginning of filename if the point is
before it, and ‘track-eol’ is non-nil.  This behavior is very handy
when editing several filenames.

If nil, "up" and "down" movement is done as in any other buffer.

You can customize this variable.
```

Then you can, for example, <kbd>M-0</kbd><kbd>C-n</kbd> to move to the beginning of the current file name.

If you don't want to permanently change the value of this user option, or if its `sometimes` setting isn't convenient enough for this purpose, then you can write a simple wrapper command:

```el
(defun my-wdired-move-bof (n)
  "Move point to the beginning of the current WDired file name.
If numeric prefix argument N is not 1, move forward N - 1 lines
first.  This is for consistency with `move-beginning-of-line',
which see."
  (interactive "^p")
  (let ((wdired-use-dired-vertical-movement t))
    (wdired-next-line (1- n))))
```

and then bind it to some "magic shortcut" key, such as <kbd>M-a</kbd> (overrides `backward-sentence`, which isn't very useful in WDired) or <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> ([reserved for users](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Key-Bindings.html)):

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'wdired
  (define-key wdired-mode-map (kbd "C-c a") #'my-wdired-move-bof))
```

---

**Edit**

As @Omar correctly pointed out in a [comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/43817/move-point-to-beginning-of-file-name-in-wdired#comment67341_43825), `my-wdired-move-bof` can be written more simply if you do not care about handling a numeric prefix argument, i.e. if you only ever want to move to the beginning of a file name on the current line:

```el
(defun my-wdired-move-bof ()
  "Move point to the beginning of the current WDired file name."
  (interactive)
  (dired-move-to-filename))
```

As you can see, this is just wrapping the `dired.el` non-interactive function `dired-move-to-filename` as an interactive command. This way you can also pass a non-`nil` argument to `dired-move-to-filename` so that it displays an error message when something goes wrong, e.g. when invoked on a non-file line.

Comment: There is a (non-interactive) function called `dired-move-to-filename`, so `my-wdired-move-bof` could (without the numeric argument handling) be implemented as simply `(dired-move-to-filename)`.

Comment: @Omar I'm aware of `dired-move-to-filename`, as that is what `wdired-next-line` is implemented in terms of. I deliberately used `wdired-next-line` in my **sample** command for several reasons: 1) `dired-move-to-filename` is, as you say, a non-interactive function from a different library, whereas `wdired-next-line` is an interactive command with a default key binding from the same library. This makes the latter a part of the user-facing API and thus far less likely to be broken backward-incompatibly.

Comment: @Omar 2) The numeric argument handling of both vanilla `wdired-next-line` and the sample `my-wdired-move-bof` is trivial and makes both commands strictly more general and thus potentially more convenient than plain `dired-move-to-filename`. 3) Since `my-wdired-move-bof` is a very thin wrapper around `wdired-next-line`, which in turn is a very thin wrapper around `dired-move-to-filename`, I saw no benefit in "simplifying" `my-wdired-move-bof` by rewriting a less general `wdired-next-line`. YMMV.

Comment: I agree with points 2 and 3 (as for 1, I think dired is pretty stable and it's already a dependency of wdired, so...). I just wanted to offer an easier to understand implementation of the basic functionality.

Comment: @Omar Indeed, thanks, that's why I updated the answer to mention your suggestion. Re: Dired's stability - if you follow `emacs-devel` you'll know that things can often change from version to version with various levels of subtlety. `dired-move-to-filename` shows signs of not being intended for external use, such as undocumented, non-intuitive, and non-interactive arguments, whereas `wdired-next-line` is not only in the subject library, but is as stable a bet as you can get.